# How can I control animations in Flutter from outside?

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

Passing state down to widgets is easy. I have a `StatefulWidget` that contains an animation with its controller. I need to be able to trigger the animation from another widget higher in my widget tree.

[image: app]

My `MainApp` should trigger the animation using a button.

[image]

As I understand `AnimationController` only has an imperative API. I can call `controller.forward()` or `controller.reverse()`. But to do this I need to expose the controller to my MainApp.

What I currently do is to keep a global variable of my state around.

```
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      ...
      body: new LogoWidget(),
    );
  }

  _startAnimation() {
    _state.restartAnimation();
  }
}

_LogoWidgetState _state; // yuk!

class LogoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  _LogoWidgetState createState() {
    _state = _LogoWidgetState();
    return _state;
  }
}

class _LogoWidgetState extends State<LogoWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  restartAnimation() {
    controller.value == 1.0 ? controller.reverse() : controller.forward();
  }
  ...
}
```

(full sourcecode [here](https://github.com/marcmo/flutter_animation_sample/blob/master/lib/main.dart))

What is a better way to deal with this?

Comment: Why does `LogoWidget` holds animation stuff if it's supposed to be controlled somewhere else ?

Comment: well...the animation-widget itself should just react to the app state...otherwise I'd have to pull out the `AnimationController` but the `MainApp` should not care about that at all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `_LogoWidgetState _state; // yuk!` out in the middle of nowhere, but you can try:

1. create `LogoWidget _myBody = LogoWidget()`, and use that for your `body:`
2. similarily, apply with `final _LogoWidgetState _state = _LogoWidgetState()`
3. then call it as `_myBody._state.restartAnimation()`

Your sample, modified:

```
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {

  LogoWidget _myBody = LogoWidget();  //<---

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      ...
      body: _myBody,  //<---
    );
  }

  _startAnimation() {
    _myBody._state.restartAnimation();  //<---
  }
}

class LogoWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final _LogoWidgetState _state = _LogoWidgetState();  //<---

  _LogoWidgetState createState() {
    return _state;
  }
}
```

But if you think `_myBody._state.restartAnimation()` is too long, you can shorten it with:

```
class LogoWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final _LogoWidgetState _state = _LogoWidgetState();  //<---

  void restartAnimation() {  //<---
    _state.restartAnimation();
  }

  _LogoWidgetState createState() {
    return _state;
  }
}
```

Then just use `_myBody.restartAnimation()`

Here's some relevant posts:

- [call method in one stateful widget from another stateful widget - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029655/call-method-in-one-stateful-widget-from-another-stateful-widget-flutter)
- [Flutter: Call a function on a child widget's state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557842/flutter-call-a-function-on-a-child-widgets-state)