# Flutter: Call a function on a child widget's state

Tags: flutter

I've created a stateful widget and its parent widget needs to call a function that lives in the child's state.

Specifically, I have a class PlayerContainer that creates a VideoPlayer and has a member variable for the VideoPlayerController. When I press the play button, my main class needs to call play() on the state's VideoPlayerController, so I created a function inside the State class, but I don't know how to access that function from the parent widget.

Is that even possible? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple application you could simply create the play button in the same Widget as the VideoPlayer. By combining the PlayerContainer with its parent you are increasing the size of the scope of the Widget State so that everything that need access to it is part of the single larger Widget.

The main ways that a child Widget can be influenced by an ancestor are: by being rebuilt with different parameters, or by listening to something that the ancestor changes. For the latter you can use an InheritedWidget somewhere about the child. If the child refers to the InheritedWidget it gets rebuilt when the IW changes. Another way is to listen to an event stream generated by the ancestor.

You may find it easiest to just build your whole page in a single build until this becomes unwieldy.

Comment: Thanks, Richard! I need to learn about InheritedWidgets... I ended up solving my problem by moving the VideoPlayerController out of state into the widget itself, and adding a play() function on the widget.

Answer (score 33):

I know that I'm pretty late to the party, but I have something that I think might help. So, you need to do four (4) things in your `VideoPlayerController` class:
1. Create an instance of your state class.
2. Create a method (play) which will be accessible in your `PlayerContainer` class
3. In your method, use the `VideoPlayerControllerState` instance to call the method in your state class.
4. Finally, when you `createState`, do so using the instance that you already created.

```
class VideoPlayerController extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerControllerState vpcs = VideoPlayerControllerState();

  void play() {
    vpcs.play();
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => vpcs;
}
```

As you see, the `play` method uses `vpcs` (the VideoPlayerControllerState instance) to call the play method already in your state class.

In your PlayerContainer class, use your member variable to call the play method.

```
class PlayerContainerState extends State<PlayerContainer> {
  VideoPlayerController _vpc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _vpc = VideoPlayerController();
  }
  ...

  void _handlePressPlay(){
    _vpc.play();
  } 
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ... //your video player widget using _vpc as your VideoPlayerController
      _vpc,
    );
  }
}
```

You can call `_handlePressPlay()` from the `onPressed` method of your play button. Alternatively, just put `_vpc.play()` in the `onPressed` method. Your choice :-).

Comment: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3819 pos 12: '_state._widget == null': is not true.

Comment: It does work. Anyways it did for me without any errors. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

While Darren Cole's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53234327/12441019) does not work correctly, there is an easy way to circumvent the immediate problem. Instead of

```
State<StatefulWidget> createState() => vpcs;

final VideoPlayerControllerState vpcs = VideoPlayerControllerState();
```

write:

```
State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
  vpcs = VideoPlayerControllerState();
  return vpcs;
}

VideoPlayerControllerState vpcs;
```

This way, the state gets re-written everytime `createState()` is called, which avoids the `Failed assertion: line 3819 pos 12: '_state._widget == null': is not true` errors.

Still, I guess this is a somewhat hackish solution - can somebody point out a better one?

Comment: On a side note: This will generate a `'must_be_immutable' warning`, but I believe with far tamer consequences than the final `State` instance.

Comment: This gives me 2 warnings though (class has mutable fields + logic in createState). Isn't there any better way?

Answer (score 6):

State management is the one thing they dropped the ball on with respect to this framework.  I've used static variables (if I need to share data between states) and GlobalKeys (for just one quick, dirty solution) to get this done. We're *supposed* to use InheritedWidgets, it's just extremely out-of-the-way for something that should be simple.  I usually just do this:

```
// top of code here - this is global
final videoPlayerKey = GlobalKey();

class VideoPlayerContainer extends StatelessWidget {
    static VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
    ...
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController(...);
        // the static variable is empty until the container is built

        return Container(
            child: VideoPlayer(
                child: PlayButton(onTap: () => 
                    videoPlayerKey.currentState.setState(
                    () => VideoPlayerContainer.videoPlayerController.play();
                ))
            ),
        ); 
    }
}

class VideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
final Key key = videoPlayerKey;
    ...
}

class VideoPlayerState extends State<VideoPlayer> {
    ...
}
```

**We need to get videoPlayerKey's currentState to use setState() and re-run the build method so it knows to update**, and then we can grab the controller for the player wherever it is stored using the static variable.  It could be in VideoPlayer or anywhere else that's not here in VideoPlayerContainer, because it's static - it's just important that you assign the GlobalKey to whatever Widget will need to be rebuilt.  It will work because whenever a user could tap the button, the static variable will have been set for any void to read by VideoPlayerContainer's build() method.  For this method, it's important to note that it's more important that you attach the GlobalKey to the element that needs to be updated - you can put the static pageController literally wherever and set it from wherever within a build() or initState().

Notes:  This will not work if you try to use multiple VideoPlayers in one layout, because GlobalKeys must be unique, and all VideoPlayers will be initialized with the same key.  This is more of a dirty hack than anything.  I am working on a more robust state management solution at the moment to solve stuff like this.

Comment: I agree. Scoped model seems like easy solution, or just using statics.